# Buffer size limitation in the client side node.js socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, client, buffer

I have a simple client in nodejs as fallows:

```
let client = new net.Socket();
   client.connect(port, ip_addr, function () {
   console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + ip_add + ':' + port);
   client.write(msg);
  });

  client.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('DATA: ' + data); ////// this part is the issue
    client.destroy();
  });
```

Actually, it is perfect, but when the server sends a 1834 bytes packet, it can just read a part of the data. I believe this is due to the buffer size of the client and the programmer is not able to control or extend it. I googled a lot about this issue, but the only hint in the related documents and projects are socket.pause() and socket.resume() which I really couldn't understand how can I use them in the client side.

Please help me to address this issue,

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. You want `client.on('data'` to be called with bigger chunks?

Comment: yes.. exactly. it's preferred that  client.on('data' reads any chunk between 1B and 2KB.

Comment: You can change the highWaterMark of the stream, but I don't know why you need it in bigger chunks. You can buffer the chunks and use them once you have the data you need.

Comment: Your guidance was very useful and I verified the highWaterMark option in documentations. It sounds great. Nevertheless, I couldn’t find any useful sample codes to show how to define these kinds of options and pass them in the client.on(‘data', method. Would you please attach some sample codes or an appropriate link to understand this approach?